# How can i translate a string array to another language?

Tags: java, android, gridview

I want to translate `gridViewStrings` to another language like Français and Deutsch:

**CustomAdapter.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayoutAndroid;
    CoordinatorLayout rootLayoutAndroid;
    GridView gridView;
    Context context;
    ArrayList arrayList;

    public static String[] gridViewStrings = {
            "ALPHABETS",
            "NUMBERS",
            "MONTH",
            "DAYS",
            "ANIMALS",
            "CALL US",

    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define gridViewStrings in /res/values/string-de/string.xml, /res/values/string-fr,/res/values/string/string.xml ...
and load it using.

```
<string-array name="gridViewString">
    <item>ALPHABETS</item>
    <item>NUMBERS</item>
    <item>MONTH</item>
    <item>ANIMALS</item>
    <item>CALL US</item>
</string-array>
```

And load it in this way:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.gridViewString);
```

After this your the translation matching the Device Setting will be loaded.

For more Information https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#Plurals

Comment: it is not warking *// 01-19 16:38:09.918 2174-2298/system_process E/NetdConnector: NDC event {600 Iface linkstate eth0 up} processed too late: 2443ms
01-19 16:38:09.918 2174-2298/system_process E/NetdConnector: NDC event {600 Iface linkstate eth0 up} processed too late: 2444ms